# How to modify an element in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there a way of changing the value of an indexed element without resorting to removing it like this?

```
// Dictionary<?,int> runningcount = …;
int value = runningcount[city];
runningcount.Remove(city);
runningcount.Add(city, ++value);
```

Comment: I am afraid to know how many people do the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to increment the value just like this:

```
runningcount[city]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do both at the same time:

```
runningcount[city] ++;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like thin when you know the key just give it a new value

```
runningcount[Keyvaluetoreplace] = newreplacedvalue;
```